# How to insert a record to table with row number in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I'm now using a stored procedure to store a SOAP web service response from XML to a table. I have finished most of it except the part which assigns a unique and persistent id for each record.

I came up with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sometable]
    SELECT 
        T.r.value('someKey[1]','char(8)') AS some_key,
        T1.r1.value('lang[1]','char(10)') AS lang,
        T1.r1.value('description[1]','char(30)') AS description,
        T1.r1.value('phone[1]','char(10)') AS phone,
        GETDATE() AS insert_time,
        NULL AS id 
    FROM 
        @xDoc.nodes('//*:SomeNode') AS T(r)
    CROSS APPLY 
        T.r.nodes('SomeList/SomeItem') AS T1(r1)    

DECLARE @id INT 

SET @id = 0 

UPDATE [dbo].[sometable] 
SET @id = id = @id + 1
```

The code above can give perfect result at the first glance. However, the id is not persistent because the SQL update will rewrite the id of whole table.

How to solve this issue?

Please tell me if any information is unclear or missing.

Comment: Why not simply use an autoincremental id?

Comment: Can you alter the table?

Comment: I'm new to back-end development, would you mind show me some reference of autoincremental id?

Comment: FDavidov I have full control to the table.

Comment: Something like this: 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server can generate auto-increment numbers for you, using the [`Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) property.

You can't change an existing column to an identity column (or an identity column to a "regular" column) using an `ALTER TABLE` statement, but you can drop the existing `id` column and re-create it as an `identity` column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sometable]
    DROP COLUMN Id;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sometable]
    ADD Id int IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Please note that identity columns should not have business meaning, as SQL Server only guarantees to automatically generate them. They are **not** guaranteed to have no gaps, and they are **not** guaranteed to be unique.

SQL Server will not reuse values that have already been generated, even if the `insert` statement that generated them failed, but there is a command to reset the `identity` column so the next time a row is inserted to the database, the `identity` will start from a new seed. This means that it's possible for an identity column to have duplicate values.